# Add columns according to the number of these

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df`:

```
    a   b    c     d     e     11   10     9     8     7    6     5    4     3      2     1
  1241 535  2354  235  Acc_1  423  2342   2342  2342  234  234  7564  5345  76      4    976
```

Context:

From `1 to 11` are account history, `1` is the most current month and `11` is the furthest. `a,b,c,d,e` are variables I got from the data.

What I want:

What I'm looking for is to standardize a size of `df`. I mean, that it always goes from 1 to 25, no matter if the account history goes up to 11 as the df example shows and that the empty values ​​are filled with 0 values.

I want this `df`:

```
    a   b    c     d     e     25   24     23    ...    8     7    6     5    4     3      2     1
  1241 535  2354  235  Acc_1    0    0      0    ...   234  234  7564  5345  76     4    976    24
```

What I tried:

```
while df.shape[1] != 30:
    df.insert(loc=5,
             column= (I dont know what to put here, but it must iterate from the missing number until it reaches 25 ),
              value=0)
```

**Another question:** while working with this df, i couldn't call the numeric columns by name `df.1` or `df['1']` for example, the error that appears to me is: `Error: 1`. What I did was use `iloc`. Why can't I call the numeric columns by their name?

Comment: You have mixed string and numeric column labels : use `df[1]` or `df['a']` etc.

Comment: I put it like that because that's how they originally are. I wanted to give as an example the closest to reality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the last column you have in the current dataframe, then calculate how many columns you want to add, create a dataframe of zeros with the desired shape and stack the initial and the new one horizontally.

```
last_col = max(map(int, filter(lambda c: isinstance(c, int), df.columns)))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.zeros((df.shape[0], 25 - last_col)),
    columns=range(last_col + 1, 26)
)
df = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1)
df[list(df.columns[:5]) + list(range(1, 26))[::-1]]
```

Output:

```
      a    b     c    d      e   25   24   23   22   21  ...    10     9  \
0  1241  535  2354  235  Acc_1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  2342  2342   

      8    7    6     5     4   3  2    1  
0  2342  234  234  7564  5345  76  4  976  

[1 rows x 30 columns]
```

I am not sure if you column names are numbers or strings, I assumed strings. If not the code should be adjusted a bit.

UPD. The comment suggests that the columns are in fact numbers. Updated the answer to handle them.

Comment: This give me error: `'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'` . I also put an `df` example in 'I want this df'

Comment: That means that the columns are numbers. I've updated the answer to handle the numbers. And also the final formatting.

Comment: I have another error: `An error ocurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max. Trace: py4j.Py4J.Exception: Method max([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist` and Im using `from pyspark.sql import *` and `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

Comment: Well, built-in `max` is overridden by `pyspark` version. You can either stop overriding it (and import only the functions you need), or find an alternative to built-in `max`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! . Everything you told me worked. This code is very intuitive and easy to understand! thank you again